# Microsoft Cognitive Services - Limit Intents in Luis Api

Tags: c#, azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

We have started experimenting with the Microsoft.CognitiveServices.Speech nuget package (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-recognize-intents-from-speech-csharp).  This is great as it allows a language model to be built up and you can specifically include the intents you want to be matched:

```
    // Creates a Language Understanding model using the app id, and adds specific intents from your model
    var model = LanguageUnderstandingModel.FromAppId("YourLanguageUnderstandingAppId");
    recognizer.AddIntent(model, "YourLanguageUnderstandingIntentName1", "id1");
    recognizer.AddIntent(model, "YourLanguageUnderstandingIntentName2", "id2");
    recognizer.AddIntent(model, "YourLanguageUnderstandingIntentName3", "any-IntentId-here");
```

However, we are building an API and will be passing text over and this will call Luis using the API endpoint, this is very basic like so:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var queryString = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(String.Empty);

                // The request header contains your subscription key
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _cognitiveSettings.SubscriptionKey);

                // The "q" parameter contains the utterance to send to LUIS
                queryString["q"] = query;

                // These optional request parameters are set to their default values
                queryString["staging"] = _cognitiveSettings.IsProduction ? bool.FalseString : bool.TrueString;
                queryString["timezoneOffset"] = "0";
                queryString["verbose"] = "true";
                queryString["spellCheck"] = "false";

                var endpointUri = $"https://westeurope.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/{_luisAppId}?{queryString}";
                var response = await client.GetAsync(endpointUri);

                var responseJson = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IntentResponseModel>(responseJson);
            }
```

Is there a way to control the intents we would want to be returned for a particular text string?  We can set verbose to true so it returns all intents with a match rating but we would prefer to be able to specify a subset of intents depending on the state and just try to match those.  It seems you can do this with the SDK using audio, can this be done using text (is there a text SDK?).

Also, is there a way for the entitites that are returned in the JSON to be matched to the intent which populated them, it looks like there is no link between the intents and the entities.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, no, there is no way to control the intents that are returned. In the app, you will need to filter on the intents returned to limit what is matched for a particular text string.